# Django get model datefield value

Tags: python, django, django-models, datefield, django-model-field

```
class Bla(Case):
    def __init__(self, model, field, condition=None, then=None, **lookups):
    la = model._meta.get_field(field).__str__
```

returns

```
<bound method Field.__str__ of <django.db.models.fields.DateField: date>>
```

How do I get the value of the date field specifically the year?

Comment: What is `model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way

```
class Bla(Case):
    def __init__(self, model, field, condition=None, then=None, **lookups):
        la = model.objects.first()
        field_object = model._meta.get_field(field)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(la)
        year = field_value.year
```